# How to extract the upper case string from the subelement's value using regex in XSLT?

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

Initial XML:

```
            <entry n="1" xml:id="_e1">
               <desc>
                  <name role="exhibitor">FOO (bar)</name>
               </desc>
```

1. I created two `name`'s child elements: `surname` and `forename`, with the same value `FOO (bar)`:

```
            <entry n="1" xml:id="_e1">
               <desc>
                  <name role="exhibitor">
                     <surname xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
                              xmlns:s="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">FOO (bar)</surname>
                     <forename xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
                               xmlns:s="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">FOO (bar)</forename>
                  </name>
            </entry>
```

but I want the `<surname>` to contain only the string in upper case (and without the parentheses, if possible), and the `<forename>` only the non-uppercased string (like below):

```
            <entry n="1" xml:id="_e1">
               <desc>
                  <name role="exhibitor">
                     <surname>FOO</surname>
                     <forename>bar</forename>
                  </name>
            </entry>
```

My XSLT:

```
    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <surname>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            </surname>
            <forename>
                <xsl:copy-of select="upper-case(.)"/>
            </forename>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

How to achieve this?

P.S. Also, I don't understand why the namespaces appear in the `surname` and `forename`.

**DEMO**

```
        <surname>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[^\p{Lu}].*$', '')"/>
        </surname>
        <forename>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '.*[^\().*\p{Lu}\p{Ll}-]', '')"/>
        </forename>
```

The final results are:

```
         <surname>AGHEMOAGHEMO</surname>
         <forename>(Louis</forename>
```

or

```
      <name role="exhibitor">
         <surname>ACCART</surname>
         <forename>(Georges-Paul)</forename>
      </name>
```

***NB*:** in the example `AGUTTE (Mme Georgette`, the `Mme` gets removed, because of the space between the `Mme` and `Georgette`.

Comment: The use of the `upper-case` function suggests you are using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor so you have `xsl:analyze-string` or (in XSLT 3) additionally the `analyze-string` function to break up complex strings. On the other hand, if all data contains one fragment in `()` it is easy to use XPath 1 string functions like `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uppercase() function does not *extract* upper-case characters; it *converts* lower-case characters to upper case.

To implement your stated logic, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <surname>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[^A-Z]', '')"/>
        </surname>
        <forename>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[^a-z]', '')"/>
        </forename>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTJx

Or, to make it less Anglo-centric (in case you have accented or Greek characters, etc.):

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <surname>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[^\p{Lu}]', '')"/>
        </surname>
        <forename>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[^\p{Ll}]', '')"/>
        </forename>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, as Martin Honnen stated in a comment to your question, this may not be the best strategy to implement here.

---

> P.S. Also, I don't understand why the namespaces appear in the `surname` and `forename`.

Probably because you are using `xsl:copy-of` (without specifying `copy-namespaces="no"`) instead of `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: Great answer, this strategy even handles the entries containing only one parenthesis, e.g. 'FOO (bar'.

Comment: I also agree with your more UTF-8-like approach. However, the `ACCART (Georges-Paul` gets split like `ACCARTGP` and `eorgesaul`, because of the capital letter of the forenames and a hyphen between them. I have tried to adjust the XSL in the demo, but now I'm getting `ACCART` and `[space]eorges-Paul` https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTJx. How could we adapt your proposition to the simple names (e. g. `AGHEMOAGHEMO (Louis)` and the composed ones (e. g. `ACCART (Georges-Paul`) (optionally, with the hyphen)?

Comment: @ljushu Now you see why this is not the best strategy. I suggest you post a new question with your new problem - and make sure we understand the rules by which the input is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND:**

Building upon the @michael.hor257k's answer, the following modification of the `.xsl` script handles different cases such as `AGHEMOAGHEMO (Louis` (with the open parenthesis), entries with the composed forename `ACCART (Georges-Paul)` including the hyphen, or `AGUTTE (Mme Georgette` without it:

```
        <surname>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[^\p{Lu}].*$', '')"/>
        </surname>
        <forename>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '.*[^\(.*\p{Lu}\p{Ll}-][^.*\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]', '')"/>
        </forename>
```

Results:

```
         <surname>AGHEMOAGHEMO</surname>
         <forename>Louis</forename>
```

```
         <surname>ACCART</surname>
         <forename>Georges-Paul)</forename> ----> closed parenthesis still there
```

```
         <surname>AGUTTE</surname>
         <forename>Mme Georgette</forename>
```